# Having trouble translating a sentence

Tags: translation, verb

Found this example sentence in one of the videos teaching Deutsch to beginners:

> "Findest du das Baby süß?"

The translation given was:

> "Do you think this baby is cute?".

But shouldn't it be something like:

> "Do you find this baby cute"?

I don't see how the form of "to be" fits into the English translation given that it is absent in the original German sentence.

Comment: "Findest Du es süß" und "Findest Du, es ist süß" sind semantisch identisch. Die passendste englische Übersetzung ist eine Frage an Fachleute für die englische Sprache.

Answer (score 2):

One of the common meanings of *etwas finden* is *to have an opinion, to think*. That's how the translation becomes *Do you think that …*

Answer (score 1):

What does "Do you find this baby cute" even mean? From [dictionary](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/find) the best fit for "find" in this sentence is "to determine an issue after judicial inquiry". While "finden" in German in this case has a similar meaning (consider something to be true), it is too informal for a court case.

The German sentence might also be written as "Findest du, das Baby ist süß?", with an explicit source for "to be". You can even consider the original sentence a short form where "ist" was omitted.

It might also be proper English to say "Do you consider the baby cute", it is the same structure as this [example](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/consider) "I consider the story improbable".

Comment: Well, [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/find) also lists "to discover or perceive (something) after thinking about it or experiencing it" as a possible meaning, and provides the example "I found it hard to believe". This seems to be pretty much the same meaning as in German.